# When you call Visa for emergeny cash how does the process actually work?

Tags: payment-cards

There is reference in other questions to an emergency cash distribution service provided by Visa if your credit card is lost or stolen.

What I can't understand is how such a service can possibly work. If my card is lost or stolen I can't read out information printed on the card. Given changes in online banking practices over the last decade or so it is also quite possible that I will not be able to access my online banking either*.

Can anyone explain to me how the process works?

* Yes I know the password, but the password is seemingly useless without being able to receive a call or SMS on a predetermined number.

Answer (score 3):

Visa will need to contact your bank or card provider in order to obtain approval, and it is during this step that you may need to provide details to your bank to approve the transaction from your account to Visa (and you do not need to remember your card number, but if you do then the process is quicker). This may require you to be present during your bank's emergency team operating hours if you do not have sufficent details at hand.

- You will need to have the emergency telephone number at hand. Visa maintains a list of freephone numbers for most countries across the world, and these numbers are routed to the US fronted call centre (probably outsourced to a country such as the India or Phillipines). You can also do a collect call to the US call centre.
- The call centre will take your details (card number if you have it, but otherwise just your name and bank) and see if you are on the system, and will then either connect you to your bank or card provider (for a remedy) or provide you an option for emergency cash.
- The emergency cash option is handled by visa, but they need to obtain approval from your bank or card provider which can take until bank opening hours depending on your banks' emergency team operating hours.

You will receive the money by Western Union (so you need to find a WU and visit it during opening hours).

A major advantage is that you can obtain access to your money for free if you don't have money for the long distance phone call to your bank.